# Android Cloud Firestore: Query to find a users name

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I've looked for multiple solutions here but couldn't find anything specific to my situation and therefore am posting a question here while I still continue looking for a solution. I'm fairly new to Firestore still and their guide/docs are still unclear.

My phone application has a system to get a user to enter in a name. This name is to be used to traverse the Firestore database and if the name exists as a field for one of the users, then the method must return a boolean of `true`.

This query is to be triggered by a "continue button" which is in my main activity as shown below:

```
    //Authenticate user and proceed to next activity
    continueBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.continue_btn);
    continueBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //On click create a db reference and perform a query on it to find current user
            //and authenticate it.
            CollectionReference myRef = database.collection("users");
            Query findNameQ = myRef.whereEqualTo("name", mUserName);
            authenticateUser(findNameQ, mUserName);//I need to pass to this method a variable 'findNameQ' which can be used to validate the existence of a user.
            //mUserName is the name it's looking for.
        }

    });
```

Once the query is run then it runs the authenticateUser method which basically validates the existence of the user and creates a new one if the user doesn't exist. Here's the method:

```
private void authenticateUser(Query findNameQ, String mUserName)
{
    //Read from database and check if user exists
    //if current users name matches to one in database then set userExists to true.
    if (findNameQ != null)
    {
        userExists = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "User exists!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
        Toast.makeText(this, "User doesn't exist!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

I'd like to use if (findNameQ != false) instead of `null`, how do I make it so my findNameQ variable is a boolean and not a query object?

Comment: You're going to have to actually execute that query.  The documentation for reading data from Firestore can be found here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data  - you should definitely familiarize yourself with how that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to know if a user name exists in Firestore database, you need to use a `get()` call. Just creating a Query object will not provide you much. Beside that, if you are checking `findNameQ != null` it will always evaluate to `true` because findNameQ object is created and will never be `null`. So to solve this, please use the following lines of code:

```
productsRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                if (document.exists()) {
                    authenticateUser(findNameQ, mUserName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Please also note, that using a `addSnapshotListener` will not help you because it will attach a listener to get data in real time but this is not what you need. You need to get the data only once.

Comment: Ah I see, so the query object will be created no matter what the resut of the query. Thank you very much. I couldn't wrap my head around the attributes of the query object.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. It doesn't matter what is the result of the query, the query object will be created. You're welcome, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boolean variable as
boolean nameFound = false;

Now, attach a snapshot listener to your query to check whether the name exists or not:

```
    findNameQ.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>(){
                @Override
                public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                    for (DocumentSnapshot ds: queryDocumentSnapshots){
                        if (ds!=null && ds.exists()){
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Username Exists!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            nameFound = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

else the default value of nameFound that is false will be used. Now, use can use if else to call your authentication method based on the value of nameFound.

Comment: If that work for you @Adrian Robertson please mark the answer as accepted by checking the tick icon on left side under my answer.